# Coredata multithread: how to filter save notification?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, notifications

I have one iOS application with coredata and thread confination.
I followed apple rules, and i created a single persistentstorecoordinator and one managedObjectContext per Thread.

Because both threads can modify the data i added a code to merge the contexts (in NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification)

Up to here everything works, but i want to refresh my GUI only when the object i'm viewing is the last merge...
I could refresh my GUI ad every NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification but i have about 15k records and one update at second. I'm really care about performance.

Comment: Just don't save so many times

Comment: my app are distribuited on 500 users..and every user can update every record. i need synch at least at every 60 sec